# How to create and format an image dataset from scratch for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I've only worked with ML with .csv formats. I've worked with image formats too but only premade imagesets (MNIST,etc). If I were to create an imageset from scratch, how are the class labels typically formated? Would I have to manually title the image of a jpeg?

Best,
Jeremy

Comment: also, jpeg images cannot be the same title, so wouldn't the ML program recognize every image as its own class if all titles different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at existing challenges around and their data format (for example http://www.kaggle.com/c/datasciencebowl/data) I would say put the images in a folder per class. You can use the file names for the index.

Comment: This is right. I asked someone at Ersatz Labs too. Same answer: group class by folder. Thanks.

Comment: by the way, for that Kaggle link. That is a TON of classes for only 30K images. Interesting. Thanks for sharing that.